# Possible to show SQLite DB data in spotlight search?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, core-data, corespotlight

Lately I am trying to use `CoreSpotlight` framework introduced in iOS 9.
I succeeded in indexing a bunch of `CSSearchableItem` and searching it in spotlight.

Previously I have few data stored in SQLITE db, How to include those datas in spotlight search without saving it again as `CSSearchableItem`?

Is it possible in the first place?

If not `SQLITE` what about `CoreData`

Comment: got any solution?? i need too